# Problem with plain text

Tags: errors

I would like to use something like this in my LaTeX document: `P29_Ampl_1`. After this I have got an error because I use `_`. I can solve it by insertign `$` between the `P29_Ampl_1` -> `$P29_Ampl_1$`. It cause that text doesn't look good. How can I solve it. I would like to use `P29_Ampl_1` as a normal plain text? Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try with `P29\_Ampl\_1`

Comment: if you have only one or two of these things, @karlkoeller's suggestion is good.  if you have lots, i would recommend a look at the `underscore` package, which makes `_` look like `\_` in text, but to retain its original meaning in maths.  (nb, the command isn't noticeably robust, i imagine.)

Comment: Many approaches (including the two mentioned in comments here) are discussed in the comments and answers at the proposed duplicate.